# What is the fastest ArangoDB friends-of-friends query (with count)

Tags: graph-databases, arangodb, aql

I'm trying to use ArangoDB to get a list of friends-of-friends. Not just a basic friends-of-friends list, I also want to know how many friends the user and the friend-of-a-friend have in common and sort the result. 
After several attempts at (re)writing the best performing AQL query, this is what I ended up with:

```
LET friends = (
  FOR f IN GRAPH_NEIGHBORS('graph', @user, {"direction": "any", "includeData": true, "edgeExamples": { name: "FRIENDS_WITH"}})
  RETURN f._id
)

LET foafs = (FOR friend IN friends
  FOR foaf in GRAPH_NEIGHBORS('graph', friend, {"direction": "any", "includeData": true, "edgeExamples": { name: "FRIENDS_WITH"}})
    FILTER foaf._id != @user AND foaf._id NOT IN friends
    COLLECT foaf_result = foaf WITH COUNT INTO common_friend_count
    RETURN {
      user: foaf_result,
      common_friend_count: common_friend_count
    }
)
FOR foaf IN foafs
  SORT foaf.common_friend_count DESC
  RETURN foaf
```

Unfortunately, performance is not as good as I would've liked. Compared to the Neo4j versions of the same query(and data), AQL seems quite a bit slower (5-10x).

What I'd like to know is...  How can I improve our query to make it perform better?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I am one of the core developers of `ArangoDB` and tried to optimize your query. As I do not have your `dataset` I can only talk about my test `dataset` and would be happy to hear if you can validate my results.

First if all I am running on `ArangoDB` 2.7 but in this particular case I do not expect a major performance difference to 2.6.

In my `dataset` I could execute your query as it is in ~7sec.
First fix:
In your friends statement you use `includeData: true` and only return the `_id`. With `includeData: false` `GRAPH_NEIGHBORS` directly returns the `_id` and we can also get rid of the subquery here

```
LET friends = GRAPH_NEIGHBORS('graph', 
                              @user,
                              {"direction": "any",
                               "edgeExamples": { 
                                   name: "FRIENDS_WITH"
               }})
```

This got it down to ~ 1.1 sec on my machine. So I expect that this will be close to the performance of Neo4J.

**Why does this have a high impact?**
Internally we first find the `_id` value without actually loading the documents JSON. In your query you do not need any of this data, so we can safely continue with not opening it.

**But now for the real improvement**

Your query goes the "logical" way and first gets users neighbors, than finds their neighbors, counts how often a `foaf` is found and sorts it.
This has to build up the complete foaf network in memory and sort it as a whole.

You can also do it in a different way:
1. Find all `friends` of user (only `_ids`)
2. Find all `foaf` (complete document)
3. For each `foaf` find all `foaf_friends` (only `_ids`)
4. Find the intersection of `friends` and `foaf_friends` and COUNT them

This query would like this:

```
LET fids = GRAPH_NEIGHBORS("graph",
                           @user,
                           {
                             "direction":"any",
                             "edgeExamples": {
                               "name": "FRIENDS_WITH"
                              }
                           }
                          )
FOR foaf IN GRAPH_NEIGHBORS("graph",
                            @user,
                            {
                              "minDepth": 2,
                              "maxDepth": 2,
                              "direction": "any",
                              "includeData": true,
                              "edgeExamples": {
                                "name": "FRIENDS_WITH"
                              }
                            }
                           )
  LET commonIds = GRAPH_NEIGHBORS("graph",
                                  foaf._id, {
                                    "direction": "any",
                                    "edgeExamples": {
                                      "name": "FRIENDS_WITH"
                                     }
                                  }
                                 )
  LET common_friend_count = LENGTH(INTERSECTION(fids, commonIds))
  SORT common_friend_count DESC
  RETURN {user: foaf, common_friend_count: common_friend_count}
```

Which in my test graph was executed in ~ 0.024 sec

So this gave me a *factor 250 faster* execution time and I would expect this to be faster than your current query in Neo4j, but as I do not have your `dataset` I can not verify it, it would be good if you could do it and tell me.

**One last thing**

With the `edgeExamples: {name : "FRIENDS_WITH" }` it is the same as with `includeData`, in this case we have to find the real edge and look into it. This could be avoided if you store your edges in separate collections based on their name. And then remove the edgeExamples as well. This will further increase the performance (especially if there are a lot of edges).

**Future**

Stay tuned for our next release, we are right now adding some more functionality to AQL which will make your case much easier to query and should give another performance boost.

Comment: Thanks! I will check, verify and accept your answer monday! We very much appreciate the fact that you took the time to answer our question ;)

Comment: In our case, your first improvement was significantly faster than our version. Especially our slowest queries benefitted from your improvements.  It did indeed bring the AQL result very close to the Neo4j version.  
As for the 2nd query - it made our worst-case foaf-queries faster, but the best-case queries a bit slower :(. Either way, the first improvement helped us a lot ;).