# friends of friend Query in ArangoDB 3.0

Tags: arangodb, aql

I want to writing 'friends of friend' traversal using **AQL**

I have a Collection with Name:**User** and a edge Collection with name **Conatct**.

my **Conatct** documents:

[image]

I also read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33279811/what-is-the-fastest-arangodb-friends-of-friends-query-with-count) that implement friends of friend in ArangoDb, but that's post Uses functions of  lower version of ArangoDB that used GRAPH_NEIGHBORS() function.

in ArnagoDB 3.0(latest version), **GRAPH_NEIGHBORS()** function have been removed!

now, how can I implement fof using Aql in ArnagoDB 3.0 ?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [graph functions have been removed](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.0/Manual/ReleaseNotes/UpgradingChanges30.html#graph-functions), because there is the more powerful, flexible and performant [native AQL traversal](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.0/AQL/Graphs/index.html), which was introduced with 2.8, and extended and optimized for version 3.0.

To retrieve friends of friends, a traversal starting at the user in question with a traversal depth = 2 is needed:

```
LET user = DOCUMENT("User/@9302796301")
LET foaf = (
  FOR v IN 2..2 ANY user Contact
    RETURN v // you might wanna return the name only here
)
RETURN MERGE(user, { foaf } )
```

The document for the user with `_key` = `@9302796301` is loaded and assigned to a variable `user`. It is used as start vertex for a traversal with min and max depth = 2, using the edges of the collection `Contact` and ignoring their direction (`ANY`; can also be `INBOUND` or `OUTBOUND`). The friends of friends documents are fully returned in this example (`v`) and merged with the `user` document, using the attribute key `"foaf"` and the value of the variable `foaf`.

This is just one simple example how to traverse graphs and how to construct result sets. There are many more options of course.